# why this is true when proofing euler summation rule?

Tags: summation

In [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363503/eulers-proof-sum-of-natural-numbers/) of euler's summation,After derivation it said that :
Second thing he assumed was:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)x^k=1-2+3-4+5-6+...=\frac{1}{4}$$
& I want to know how we can get to this . Thanks

Comment: Just place $x=-1$ in the derivative equation...

Comment: When people answer your questions, it really is polite to acknowledge them...

Comment: Thanks for your answer.& sorry I saw it just now:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement, which you quoted correctly, wasn't quite written correctly in the first place, at a glance. It should say that the sum, **when $-1=x$**, gives that series. Simply write $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)(-1)^k$ and for $k=0$, we get $1$. For $k=1$, we have $-2$, and so on. This was what N74's comment meant.

Beyond that, the series is divergent. We see that the partial sums are $1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3$, etc. So when they say Euler "assumed", we really mean he did just that. There is no proof because it isn't correct. The sum does not have a value in the classical sense, but in a heuristic sense (Euler did a lot of this sort of hand-waving, if you ask me, and it is amazing he got away with it).